# How to make my Unity 3d (AR) project play in a full screen on my phone?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Testing Augmented Reality made with Unity 3d and vuforia on my android device is not showing in full screen !

I have tried to change everything in unity player settings but nothing changed

i even tried to do a script for the AR Camera

```
public class fullscreen : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() =>
        // Toggle fullscreen
        Screen.fullScreen = !Screen.fullScreen;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

but it didnt work

I want to show it in the full screen

check my image[on Android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MT9s.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your game is in fullscreen `Screen.fullScreen = !Screen.fullScreen;` will make your game not fullscreen anymore. Use `Screen.fullScreen = true;`

Then, under Project Settings -> Player -> Resolution and Presentation check Start in fullscreen mode.

Comment: i have tried your solution but, it didnt work...same results :(

Comment: Is your whole app an UI ? If so, are you in ScreenSpace-Overlay with the resolution you want ?
If it's not that I don't know, sorry :x

Comment: yes i think my problem is the screen space overlay, i dont know :( im new with unity and vuforia and its my first project.. i have searched for everything to make it full screen on my phone

Comment: I never used Vuforia, so if it's related to it I can't help, try asking for help in Unity forum directly maybe

Comment: i think vuforia is not the problem may there is another way to make it full screen in the player setting ..i dont know, anyway thanks for help :)